# Canno't to save cookies on chrome

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, cookies

I want to save cookies on client which i get from server.
On Firefox everything is fine, but chrome still show "This Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url"

I've readed lot of tutorials but i still can't figure it our.

It works fine on localhost, but when i tried to host it on heroku, i get this warning on chrome, and can't save cookie.

I created test project on Heroku, and client is at "https://cookietestclient.herokuapp.com", and server is at "https://cookieservertest.herokuapp.com/"

This is my JS fetch code:

```
function addCookie (){
fetch("https://cookieservertest.herokuapp.com/api/v1/test",{
    method:"POST",
    credentials:"include",
    mode:"cors"
})
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(data=>{
      console.log(data)
    })
}
```

And Spring Boot code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/test")
public class BasicReturnCookie {

    @PostMapping
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "https://cookietestclient.herokuapp.com", allowCredentials = "true", 
allowedHeaders = "https://cookietestclient.herokuapp.com", maxAge = 3600)
    public void getMapping(HttpServletResponse response){

        ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("userName", "Jarek")
                .domain("/")
                .sameSite("None")
                .build();

        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies with SameSite=None must now also specify the Secure attribute (they require a secure context/HTTPS).

```
ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("userName", "Jarek")
            .domain("/")
            .sameSite("None")                // <- delete this
            .build();
```

Comment: It's not working. Even if i added Secure and HttpOnly

Comment: What do you mean by "If i added secure"? Are you setting secure to true?